# Please explain this hardcore macro that does casting and typechecking

Tags: c++, c, macros, types, casting

The following code is from an existing application that has to be compiled in both C and C++. There's a macro:

```
/* Type-checking macro to provide arguments for CoCreateInstance() etc.
 * The pointer arithmetic is a compile-time pointer type check that 'obj'
 * really is a 'type **', but is intended to have no effect at runtime. */
#define COMPTR(type, obj) &IID_##type, \
(void **)(void *)((obj) + (sizeof((obj)-(type **)(obj))) \
                - (sizeof((obj)-(type **)(obj))))
```

that is used as follows:

```
ISomeInterface *object;
CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_SomeInterfaceImpl, NULL,
     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, COMPTR(ISomeInterface, &object))));
```

here the idea is that the last two parameters of `CoCreateInstance()` are `IID&` and `void**` and that macro grabs `ISomeInterface**` and converts it to `IID&` and `void**` at the same time enforcing a compile-time check that the address passed in place of `ISomeInterface**` is indeed an address of `ISomeInterface*` pointer variable.

Okay, but what's the need for

```
((obj) + (sizeof((obj)-(type **)(obj))) \
     - (sizeof((obj)-(type **)(obj)))
```

complex expression? I see that the type checking is enforced with `(obj)-(type**)(obj)` subexpression. What's the need for adding and then subtracting the `sizeof()`? And what's the need for casting to `void*` before casting to `void**`?

I suppose the same can be done as follows:

```
#define COMPTR(type, obj) &IID_##type, \
(void **)(sizeof((obj)-(type**)(obj)), obj)
```

here the first part of comma operator would contain a `sizeof()` that would enforce the typecheck and evaluate to a constant, the second part would just yield the same pointer and the pointer would be cast to `void**`.

What can the original macro do what the one I suggest can't? What's the need for those complications?

Comment: And this is why this is bad code. Let me guess, you've been struggling with this all day?

Comment: @nightcracker: No, I don't maintain that code, I just found it and was curious how it works.

Comment: +1 for hardcore in the title, should be a tag!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the original author wasn't aware of the comma operator? This is not exactly unheard of among C/C++ programmers.

Comment: Surprisingly few C programmers I've worked with know of the comma operator.

Comment: Some projects have programming standards that outlaw the use of the comma operator. <sarcasm>A macro that uses forbidden syntax! Heaven forbid! It is so much better to use obscure syntax and to write an additive zero (or multiplicative one) in a rather creative way than it is to use the comma operator or the teriary operator.</sarcasm>

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the original author wasn't aware of function templates. This macro is begging to be replaced by a function template.

Apparently the fourth argument to `CoCreateInstance` is a pointer to some global object of type IID that pertains to the `type` (type argument to COMPTR) at hand. The fifth and final argument to `CoCreateInstance` is supposed to be a `type**` pointer.

Instead, the function `CoCreateInstance` takes a `void**` (yech!) pointer as its last argument, obtained by casting the supposed `type**` pointer. The cast goes through `void*` as an intermediary because any pointer can be cast to/from a void* pointer.

Sans the protection in that COMPTR macro, one could pass a `double*` pointer, or even a `long long` (not a pointer!) as the fifth argument to `CoCreateInstance`. Of course, this whole mess would have been avoided had the original author used C++ what its very good at, type safety. Instead he/she decided to go the void* pointer route and put the protection in the macro.

What the goofiness is doing: The argument to `sizeof` is the pointer difference expression `(obj)-(type**)(obj)`. If `obj` is a `type**` pointer, this is 0 (as type ptrdiff_t). If `obj` is something else, this pointer difference expression is ill-formed. So, two cases, `obj` is a `type**` pointer, or it isn't.

Case 1, `obj` is a `type**` pointer: The pointer difference expression is valid, so the last argument to `CoCreateInstance` expands to `(void**)(void*)(obj+8-8)`, assuming a 64 bit machine. (The +8-8 becomes +4-4 on a 32 bit machine.) Regardless of machine size, the offset is added and subtracted, leaving the original pointer.

Case 2, `obj` is not a `type**` pointer: The pointer difference expression is ill-formed, so the code doesn't compile.

Comment: Please note there're no templates in C and code is to be compiled in both C and C++ and also `CoCreateInstance()` is a Win32 function that serves as a global class factory that can't be specific to any interface and that's exactly why it accepts `void**`.

Comment: @sharptooth: Did you downvote? Note that I did explain how exactly this macro works.

Comment: Nope, I didn't downvote, I just clarified those two rather important points - that templates couldn't be used here and that `void**` is there for a reason.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from writing a type safe, C++ specific way of invoking `CoCreateInstance` using templates (and possibly a C++ specific macro because of that `&IID_##type` argument).